# Number of surjective function from clousure of A to Q

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a connected open subset of $\mathbb R^2$. The number of continuous surjective functions from clousure of $A\to\mathbb Q$ is

1) 1

2) 0

3) 2

4) $\infty$

Please solve this. I can't find a way to find its solution.. Plz solve in details, its my request

Comment: Answer is 0. Because is Q is totally disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: the continuous image of a connected space is connected.